# How to create a custom action column in kartik gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, kartik-v

I am trying to create a column that displays a glyphicon. The glyphicon will link to an url which allows the user to download a file. Any help would be massively appreciated. Current code is as follows:

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'pager' => [
    'class' => 'common\widgets\Pagination',
],
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'label' => 'Date',
        'attribute' => 'call_datetime',
        'format' => 'date',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Time',
        'attribute' => 'call_datetime',
        'format' => 'time',

    ],
    'call_from',
    'call_to',
    'duration',
    'call_type',
    'extension',

    [
        'label' => 'File',
        'attribute' => 'fname',
        'value' => 'callRecFiles.fname',
    ],
```

It is the last attribute 'fname' that the user will be downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `fname` field array to:

```
[
    'label' => 'File',
    'attribute' => 'fname',
    'value' => function($model) {
         //here create glyphicon with URL pointing to your action where you can download file, something like 
         return $model->callRecFiles ? Html::a('Download', ['myController/download-action', 'fname' => $model->callRecFiles->fname]) : null;
    }
],
```

And prepare proper action to allow user to download file.

Comment: Thank you again @Yupik.  However until I added 
`'format' => 'raw'`
link was displaying as plain text

Comment: Thank you, Yupik. Thanks Kyle for the helpful comment.